How to create a Textfield with filled color and different border?
I need to create a text file in Flutter with a filled color. However, it should have a border in the editing area and a white suffix icon. See the attached screenshot of the Figma design.
In the textfiled's fillColor property it fill whole textfiled.
Someone, please help to achieve this in flutter


Try a Container with a Row of Textfield and Icon.

As you required suffixIcon and Icon in same Row use Container like below
Use FocusNode for change border color of Container while focus on TextField
Color borderColorContainer = Colors.grey;
final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        borderColorContainer = Colors.red;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

Here is the Container
          Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.white,
             border: Border.all(color: borderColorContainer, width: 0.5),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              child: Row(
                     children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              focusNode: focusNode,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward_outlined),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Color(0xfff8f8f8)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Color(0xfff8f8f8)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                filled: true, // Enables filled color
                                fillColor: Color(0xfff8f8f8), // Background color

                                hintText: 'Enter text',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12), // Add padding if needed

                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Colors.blue, // Color of the icon
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),


thank you, for the answer. but 1 more question. how to change the border color of the container accordingly when text field have focus or has an error?

I have updated my answer with change Container border color while focus on TextFiled.

Try below code hope it helps to you.
I have take Container and TextFormField widget and wrap my TextFormField inside Container and make some changes according to your provided UI.
Code:
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('Add Batch Number'),
          SizedBox(height: 3),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.grey.shade400,
              ),
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),

Result Screen

Thanx for your answer and your efforts. :)

@Priyanka if help to you please upvote and accept it, enjoy your ride with Flutter

above answer helped me :)
